# javascript arrow key movement in html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to javascript and i'm trying to make a maze game, i move with arrows and wasd, but i can't figure out how to move with html buttons for touch devices, here is my js code:

```
    function moveRect(e) {
        var estado = new Boolean(false); //variable to know if the player won or not
        var pos = []; //saves every position player moves to
        var newX;
        var newY;
        var canMove; // i'm not using this right now
        e = e || window.event;
        moveA = 22; //1
        moveB = 22; //22
        var angle = 0;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38:   // upkey
                newX = currRectX;
                newY = currRectY - moveA;
                angle = 90;
                break;
            case 87: // W key
                newX = currRectX;
                newY = currRectY - moveB;
                angle = 90;
                break;
            case 37: // leftkey
                newX = currRectX - moveA;
                newY = currRectY;
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case 65: // A key
                newX = currRectX - moveB;
                newY = currRectY;
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case 40: // downkey
                newX = currRectX;
                newY = currRectY + moveA;
                angle = 270;
                break;
            case 83: // S key
                newX = currRectX;
                newY = currRectY + moveB;
                angle = 270;
                break;
            case 39: //rightkey
                newX = currRectX + moveA;
                newY = currRectY;
                break;
            case 68: // D key
                newX = currRectX + moveB;
                newY = currRectY;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
```

now i'm trying to figure out how to add this to an html button, for example, left button do what a key and left key do.

I've tried `jQuery` like this

```
$('#left-btn').click();
$('#right-btn').click();
```

but i don't know how to pass what i already have coded as a parameter for the `click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything that you want. 
 Don't forget to declare your variables out of that function's scope.

```
$('#left-btn').click(function(){
  //do your things here
  //e.g.
  x    -= 10;
  angle = 50;
});
```

See more:
https://api.jquery.com/click/